# Is possible that Apollo has a path to listen from webhook restful third party

Tags: webhooks, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have an Apollo and a third party webhooks such as Github webhook for hook a event to my Apollo.
How do Apollo create a path or detach webhook. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to migrate to [`apollo-server-express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-express) to add endpoints for the webhook to listen to.